# Displaying custom taxonomy related to each post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

my site has 3 custom post types that each post type has a unique custom taxonomy to that post type.

I want to display these taxonomies in my single posts page and just the taxonomy related to that post type and not the others and without categories and tags.

setting the _builtin to false would do the trick for categories and tags but I can't figure out the way to display those custom taxonomies properly and my posts page show all custom taxonomies from all post types.

I don't know php perfectly and tried to find the code from multiple sites including this site and this is my code so far:

```
// get taxonomies terms links
function custom_taxonomies_terms_links() {
    global $post, $post_id;
    // get post by post id
    $post = &get_post($post->ID);
    // get post type by post
    $post_type = $post->post_type;
    // get post type taxonomies
    $args = array(
        'public'   => true,
        '_builtin' => false
    ); 

    $output = 'names'; // or objects
    $operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
    $taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $args, $output, $operator );

    $out = "<ul>";

    foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {        
        $out .= "<li>".$taxonomy.": ";
        // get the terms related to post
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );

        if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
            foreach ( $terms as $term )
                $out .= '<a href="' .get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy) .'">'.$term->name.'</a> ';
        }

        $out .= "</li>";
    }

    $out .= "</ul>";

    return $out;
}
```

any help will be appreciated.tnx

Comment: You should use https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_object_taxonomies to get the all taxonomies related to the custom posttype,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below Code

```
function custom_taxonomies_terms_links() 
{
    global $post, $postid;

    $custom_taxonomies = get_post_taxonomies( $post );

    if($custom_taxonomies)
    {
        foreach ($custom_taxonomies as $custom_taxonomy) 
        {
              // get post type taxonomies
            $args = array(
                'public'   => true,
                '_builtin' => false
            ); 
            $args['name']=$custom_taxonomy;

            $output = 'names'; // or objects
            $operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
            $taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $args, $output, $operator );

            $out = "<ul>";

            foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) 
            {        
                    $out .= "<li>".$taxonomy.": ";
                    // get the terms related to post
                    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );

                    if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
                        foreach ( $terms as $term )
                            $out .= '<a href="' .get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy) .'">'.$term->name.'</a> ';
                    }

                    $out .= "</li>";
            }

            $out .= "</ul>";

            echo $out;
        }
    }
}
```

you can modify HTML tag placement in above code as per your requirement. Hope this will help you!